# Tracking users and visits (web sessions)

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I need to track users and their visits in a website. Also I need to track some actions they do in my website based on their anonymous user id and anonymous visit id.

One way is to create two different cookies that will identify visit and users. But I use also google analytics which has already such cookies

**My questions is**: is it OK to track my actions based on _ga and _gid that Google Analytics provide, or should I create my own tracking cookies?

Answer (score 1):

This is a scenario where I would not try to re-invent the wheel. Why do not you simply [re-use existing code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/) when it clearly satisfy your needs? This approach will save you time (design, implementation and more importantly code maintenance and security).